# Trying to set file upload limit in mup/nginx-proxy

Tags: nginx, mup

I am running into a file upload error with files > 10M. I have followed the advice here: http://meteor-up.com/docs.html#advanced-configuration which says how to set it in the nginx proxy by setting the `clientUploadLimit: '50M'`

I pushed the changes using `mup proxy reconfig-shared`, and it told me it had restarted the proxy. It didn't work, I still get the 413 (Request Entity Too Large) error.

I checked inside the nginx-proxy docker instance, and the file `/etc/nginx/conf.d/my_proxy.conf` has the correct entry `client_max_body_size 50M`. I restarted the EC2 box to make sure, but it's still not working.

This article https://www.tecmint.com/limit-file-upload-size-in-nginx/ suggests that the setting needs to go inside a http block, like this:

> By default, Nginx has a limit of 1MB on file uploads. To set file upload size, you can use the client_max_body_size directive, which is part of Nginx’s ngx_http_core_module module. This directive can be set in the http, server or location context.

```
http {
    client_max_body_size 100M;
}
```

I can't see how to achieve this, as the .conf file is read only and somehow locked.

Any ideas on how to proceed?

I suppose I could try a custom nginx.conf file, but I'm not sure what should go in there, and in fact whether it will even improve the situation.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: What is the size of the file you are trying to upload?

Comment: Is there any other proxies between your machine and the final application? Maybe it's not nginx that's blocking the file upload.

Comment: No, nothing in between, Good thought though

Comment: The file is 14MB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm happy to report that I solved it... I will explain how.

I was setting the limit in the nginx reverse proxy in the `mup.js` file

```
  proxy: {
    domains: 'website.com,www.website.com',
    shared: { clientUploadLimit: '50M' }
  }
```

But it turns out that there is an option to set it for each independent server like this:

```
  proxy: {
    domains: 'website.com,www.website.com',
    clientUploadLimit: '50M'
  }
```

The limit was being set to `10M` by default. I found it by shelling into the nginx-proxy docker image and doing a search with the command `grep -R client_max_body_size /etc/nginx` and it showed me all the places where it was set (for each vhost)

So I changed the `mup.js` file for my server, did a `mup stop`, and a `mup setup` (to re-do the settings) and then a `mup deploy`

Answer (score 0):

Now this is speculation but have you tried going to the docker container's root shell changed the permissions to give write permission to root or your user `chmod 760 /etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and edit the nginx file there?

Comment: @Mikkel what's the command you use to run your docker image?

Comment: I'm not sure as that's handled by meteor-up. I'm happy to say that I solved it - I'll post an answer to explain